# SQL Server trigger to save row revisions on UPDATE and INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following SQL Server trigger that I want to do the following:

- On `INSERT`, save the new row in `Documents` into `ArchivedDocuments`
- On `UPDATE`, save the new row revision **if** `WordCount` or `PageCount` or `ContributorCount` have changed from the current values with the `UPDATE`

How do I achieve this?

My current trigger just saves to `ArchivedDocument` after each `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

**EDIT**: `Id` is the primary key for the document table. `DocumentId` is a foreign key that references `Document.Id`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRG__Documents] 
ON [Documents]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset();

    INSERT INTO [DocumentRevisions] ([DocumentId], [Time], [WordCount], [PageCount], [ContributorCount])
        SELECT
            [inserted].[Id],
            @now,
            [inserted].[WordCount],
            [inserted].[PageCount],
            [inserted].[ContributorCount]
        FROM  
            [inserted]
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `EXCEPT` any matching rows in the `deleted` table. I assume `Id` is the primary key, if not then you will need to modify this to include the primary key.

```sql
create trigger [TRG__Documents] on [Documents]
    after insert, update
    as
    begin
        set nocount on;
        if(not exists (select 1 from inserted))
            return;

        declare @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset();
        insert into [dbo].[DocumentRevisions] (
            [DocumentId],
            [Time],
            [WordCount],
            [PageCount],
            [ContributorCount]
        )
        select
            i.[Id],
            @now,
            i.[WordCount],
            i.[PageCount],
            i.[ContributorCount]
        from (
            select
                i.[Id],
                i.[WordCount],
                i.[PageCount],
                i.[ContributorCount]
            from inserted i
            except
            select
                d.[Id],
                d.[WordCount],
                d.[PageCount],
                d.[ContributorCount]
            from deleted d
        ) i
    end
```

Comment: You should be ok then. I've also added an early bail-out for zero row inserts, which is best to have also, as it prevents the rest of the trigger from running at all, avoiding compilation costs and locking.